# How to get more gigs from fixers?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

I understand CDPR changed how fixers work so that you need to earn gigs by doing gigs. However, I've done all available gigs and no more are showing up.

Yet per the UI the fixers still have remaining gigs. For example I've done 3/10 for Dakota. I've tried visiting her and also driving around the badlands.

Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

The number of available gigs is related to your Street Cred level

[image]

> There are a total of 69 gigs in Night City and they are separated into four Tiers. The more Street Cred you gain, the higher level of difficulties you unlock and with that the challenges increase as well and more dangers await you. [Source](https://vulkk.com/2020/12/11/what-is-street-cred-in-cyberpunk-2077-and-how-it-works)

Increasing Street Cred is relatively easy and it can be increased by doing gigs, NCPD alerts or by simply incapacitating enemies that have their own Street Cred (so killing residents won't work), which you can see when scan targets. There is also a clothing mod that lets you increase the street cred gain